# Plotting nonlinear Diff equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Here is 3 nonlinear Diff Equation as :

[image: Nonlinear Diff Equation]

How is it possible to plot this Equation in Matlab.

Comment: First, you should split your problem into subproblems: (1) solve the differential equation and (2) plot the obtained result.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the differential equation solver in matlab, [ode45](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html?).

```
f1 = @(t,y)[-y(2)^3 - y(1)^3; y(1)*y(3) - y(2)^3; -y(3) + y(1)^2];
[time,Y] = ode45(f1,[0 10],zeros(3,1))
plot(time,Y)
```